# Micro-service: How to provide an aggregated documentation?

Tags: microservices, documentation, contract

Here is a simple use case to illustrate my question : imagine a bank mobile app, the features to implement are:

1. List the beneficiaries
2. Do a payment

We have one micro-service to handle the payments "PaymentService" and one to deal with the beneficiaries "BeneficiaryService". Both have a documented contract with RAML or OpenAPI.

I think it's not a good idea to let the mobile app call the two micro-services independently: it would expose too much the internal structure of the information system and provide no abstraction and so no mitigation.

So, we need to build a "facade" API that expose the routes of "PaymentService" + "BeneficiaryService" to ease the integration. Let's call it "MyAwesomeMobileApp"

I assume "MyAwesomeMobileApp" can be achieved by writing code (i.e. via an ESB or a dedicated Spring app) or via an API Gateway by configuration.

The thing is how do you provide aggregated documentation to your customer (the people coding the mobile app frontend) ?

By aggregated documentation I mean, a documentation with a set of routes from "PaymentService" and from "BeneficiaryService". A sort of third contract made with a subset of each micro-services.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're providing (requiring) a gateway API between the application and the other services (which seems like a good choice in your example), you provide documentation only for the gateway API endpoints as the services it consumes are not relevant to the mobile app developer.

The way your facade implements communication with any services behind it could well be different than the services themselves (for example: hiding a field that is for internal use or using different field names) and, as such, the contract even for the service-specific models could well be different.

So, document the facade/gateway API well (and independently) and be on your way.  It should internally have brokers or some other separation between the endpoints it exposes and the specific requirements of the services it consumes that allows them to be independently updated without too-tight coupling.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I have to produce contract for each micro-services, my facade is like a concatenation of the contracts. Do you know if there is a tool to concatenate contracts ?

Comment: Without knowing the language and tooling you're using, I can't make any recommendation specifically.  In general, it's common for API documentation to be generated as JSON documents (as in OpenAPI) which would be relatively easy to combine and/or selectively combine.  Again, though, part of the point of a facade is to obfuscate details behind it so I maintain that simply reusing documents from services behind it is too-tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple concatenation of the contracts or in other words a "unified" public documentation that contains endpoints from both API specification documents/contracts, then you can give [APIMatic's merging feature](https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/) a try.

A detailed step-by-step walkthrough can be found here: https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#merging-two-api-specifications---a-basic-example . However, in brief, the steps for your scenario can be:

1. Structure your API contracts in a root directory like shown in an example below:

```
dir\
  payments\  
    openapi.json
  beneficiary\
    main.raml
  APIMATIC-META.json
```

Here `openapi.json` and `main.raml` can be your OpenAPI and RAML contracts respectively.

2. A minimalistic `APIMATIC-META.json` configuration file can look like this to enable merging:

```
{
    "MergeConfiguration": {
        "MergedApiName": "My title",
        "MergeApis": true
    }
}
```

3. ZIP the directory, upload it and import it into the APIMatic Dashboard (You will need to sign up first).
4. Preview your public documentation by doing Generate > Proceed > Preview API Portal. Publish/host it as required.

If you are looking to automate the process, APIMatic has an API too: https://www.apimatic.io/docs/api#/http